# How can I extract all the rows and create a 10x10 matrix from a 100x1 matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab

r = randi(10,100,1);
I want to create a 10x10 matrix from the r matrix above
1st row will have the 10 first elements the 2nd row the next 10 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the reshape command. For instance,

```
M = reshape(r,10,10)';
```

Comment: Note that `'` will conjugate the values if they are complex. `.'` should be used instead